# Custom Background for each page and post

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, custom-background

I've created a custom background metabox and was able to call it on multiple post types and posts. I have 2 issues need your help please.

1. Is it possible to include also custom taxonomies and post categories.
2. The below code is showing an old fashion Color Picker and Image uploader, I tried to modify it for a new version didn't work

The code as following:

```
/**
 * Generate Wordpress Metabox
 */
class Contentt_Meta_Box {
    private $screens = array(
        'post', 'page', 'sp_event', 'scoreboard', 'sp_event', 'sp_team', 'sp_player', 'sp_staff', 'sp_official',
    );
    private $fields = array(
        array(
            'id' => 'background-color',
            'label' => 'Background Color',
            'type' => 'color',
            // 'desc' => esc_html__( 'Choose the background color', 'Contentt' ),
            'class' => 'button wp-color-result',
            'default'=> '',
            'rgba' => true,
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'background-image',
            'label' => 'Background Image',
            'type' => 'media',
            'class' => 'images-field clearfix',
            'field' => 'single'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'background-repeat',
            'label' => 'Background Repeat',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array(
                'no-repeat' => 'No Repeat',
                'repeat' => 'Repeat',
                'repeat-x' => 'Repeat X',
                'repeat-y' => 'Repeat Y',
            ),
            'class' => 'select-field csfield',                  
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'background-size',
            'label' => 'Background Size',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array(
                'cover' => 'Cover',
                'auto' => 'Auto',
                'contain' => 'Contain',
                'initial' => 'Initial',
            ),
            'class' => 'select-field csfield',
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'background-attachment',
            'label' => 'Background Attachment',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array(
                'fixed' => 'Fixed',         
                'scroll' => 'Scroll',
                'local' => 'Local',
                'initial' => 'Initial',
                'inherit' => 'Inherit',
            ),
            'class' => 'select-field csfield',
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'background-position',
            'label' => 'Background Position',
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array(
                'left top' => 'Left Top',
                'left center' => 'Left Center',
                'left bottom' => 'Left Bottom',
                'right top' => 'Right Top',
                'right center' => 'Right Center',
                'right bottom' => 'Right Bottom',
                'center top' => 'Center Top',
                'center center' => 'Center Center',
                'center bottom' => 'Center Bottom',
                'initial' => 'Initial',
            ),
            'class' => 'select-field csfield',
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'background-class',
            'label' => 'Background Class',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
    );

    /**
     * Class construct method. Adds actions to their respective WordPress hooks.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_footer', array( $this, 'admin_footer' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_post' ) );
        // add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'admin_script_loader'));
    }


    function admin_script_loader() {
        global $pagenow;
        if (is_admin() && ($pagenow=='post-new.php' || $pagenow=='post.php')) {
            wp_enqueue_style('fs-metabox', get_template_directory_uri() .'/includes/assets/css/metabox.css');
            wp_enqueue_media();
            wp_enqueue_script('meta-box', get_template_directory_uri() .'/includes/assets/js/meta.box.js');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hooks into WordPress' add_meta_boxes function.
     * Goes through screens (post types) and adds the meta box.
     */
    public function add_meta_boxes() {
        foreach ( $this->screens as $screen ) {
            add_meta_box(
                'background',
                __( 'Background', 'Contentt' ),
                array( $this, 'add_meta_box_callback' ),
                $screen,
                'advanced',
                'default'
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates the HTML for the meta box
     * 
     * @param object $post WordPress post object
     */
    public function add_meta_box_callback( $post ) {
        wp_nonce_field( 'background_data', 'background_nonce' );
        $this->generate_fields( $post );
    }

    /**
     * Hooks into WordPress' admin_footer function.
     * Adds scripts for media uploader.
     */
    public function admin_footer() {
        ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /*
     * Attaches the image uploader to the input field
     */
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        // Instantiates the variable that holds the media library frame.
        var background_image_frame;

        // Runs when the image button is clicked.
        $('.fs-metabox-media').click(function(e){

            // Prevents the default action from occuring.
            e.preventDefault();

            // If the frame already exists, re-open it.
            if ( background_image_frame ) {
                background_image_frame.open();
                return;
            }

            // Sets up the media library frame
            background_image_frame = wp.media.frames.background_image_frame = wp.media({
                title: '<?php _e( 'Background selection', 'Contentt' )?>',
                button: { text: '<?php _e( 'Pick background image', 'Contentt' )?>' },
                library: { type: 'image' }
            });

            // Runs when an image is selected.
            background_image_frame.on('select', function(){

                // Grabs the attachment selection and creates a JSON representation of the model.
                var media_attachment = background_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

                // Sends the attachment URL to our custom image input field.
                $('#background-image').val(media_attachment.url);

                // Sets the preview image to the same value
                $('#background-image-preview').attr('src', media_attachment.url);
            });

            // Opens the media library frame.
            background_image_frame.open();
        });


        // Removing video embed
        $(".remove-value").click(function() {
            $(this).closest("fieldset").hide().siblings(".value-adder").show().siblings(".value-field").find("input").val(null);
            return false;
        });

    });
  </script>

<?php
    }

    /**
     * Generates the field's HTML for the meta box.
     */
    public function generate_fields( $post ) {
        $output = '';
        foreach ( $this->fields as $field ) {
            $label = '<label class="field-title" for="' . $field['id'] . '">' . $field['label'] . '</label>';
            $db_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'background_' . $field['id'], true );
            switch ( $field['type'] ) {
                case 'media':
                    $input = sprintf(
                        '<input class="regular-text" id="%s" name="%s" type="text" value="%s"> <img src="%s" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail" alt="" id="background-image-preview" ><input class="button fs-metabox-media" id="%s_button" name="%s_button" type="button" value="Upload" />',
                        $field['id'],
                        $field['id'],
                        $field['id'],
                        $db_value,
                        $field['id'],
                        $field['id']
                    );
                    break;
                case 'select':
                    $input = sprintf(
                        '<select id="%s" name="%s">',
                        $field['id'],
                        $field['id']
                    );
                    foreach ( $field['options'] as $key => $value ) {
                        $field_value = !is_numeric( $key ) ? $key : $value;
                        $input .= sprintf(
                            '<option %s value="%s">%s</option>',
                            $db_value === $field_value ? 'selected' : '',
                            $field_value,
                            $value
                        );
                    }
                    $input .= '</select>';
                    break;
                default:
                    $input = sprintf(
                        '<input %s id="%s" name="%s" type="%s" value="%s">',
                        $field['type'] !== 'color' ? 'class="regular-text"' : '',
                        $field['id'],
                        $field['id'],
                        $field['type'],
                        $db_value
                    );
            }
            $output .= $this->row_format( $label, $input );
        }
        echo '<table class="form-table"><tbody>' . $output . '</tbody></table>';
    }

    /**
     * Generates the HTML for table rows.
     */
    public function row_format( $label, $input ) {
        return sprintf(
            '<tr><th scope="row">%s</th><td>%s</td></tr>',
            $label,
            $input
        );
    }
    /**
     * Hooks into WordPress' save_post function
     */
    public function save_post( $post_id ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['background_nonce'] ) )
            return $post_id;

        $nonce = $_POST['background_nonce'];
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'background_data' ) )
            return $post_id;

        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
            return $post_id;

        foreach ( $this->fields as $field ) {
            if ( isset( $_POST[ $field['id'] ] ) ) {
                switch ( $field['type'] ) {
                    case 'email':
                        $_POST[ $field['id'] ] = sanitize_email( $_POST[ $field['id'] ] );
                        break;
                    case 'text':
                        $_POST[ $field['id'] ] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ $field['id'] ] );
                        break;
                }
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'background_' . $field['id'], $_POST[ $field['id'] ] );
            } else if ( $field['type'] === 'checkbox' ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'background_' . $field['id'], '0' );
            }
        }
    }
}
new Contentt_Meta_Box;
```

As the following Images:

[image]

Comment: Any advice? Try to develop something yourself and ask the question when you got stuck with development.

Comment: I was developing it myself until I found this solution which was better then mine however I found some errors which aren't being resolved at my end. THank you!

Comment: @MaxYudin please check the code I managed yet not finding the right solution.

Comment: Hello I found a good solution and modified the code but I still have an issue, please check the edited version.

Answer (score 0):

Create meta box with meta filds which count you needed. Image field for background image, text field for other fields. Also for color field you can include jquery color picker. If you haven`t experience with WordPress metabox API - i can recommend Advanced Custom Fields plugin for this. 
Solution what you found - not bad an example. Complete all your tasks like this coded in found solution.

Comment: thank you for the answer this is what I've tried to apply however the end result wasn't as expected please check my code.

Comment: Hello I found a good solution and modified the code but I still have an issue, please check the edited version.